# VS 2015 shortcut for "GoTo Region" #region / #endregion

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-macros

Visual studio 2012 was having a working keyboard shortcut for moving to and fro between `#region` and `#endregion`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

This was not documented anywhere and this was indeed a keyboard shortcut for moving to and fro between `{` and `}`. But the same shortcut was working for regions.

See below SO question which is similar.

[How to jump to the region header from the endregion tag in c# visual studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13521604/1184435)

Visual studio 2015 seems to have stopped supporting this keyboard shortcut for regions.

I have googled and found below links.

[1. Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

and

[2. Visual Studio 2015 keyboard shortcuts - The complete list](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)

But I haven't been able to find the keyboard shortcut for `"Goto Region"`.

Has anyone found an alternate keyboard shortcut for this? OR written a macro or something for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this and everthing works fine for me. There are some issues on GitHub for this case.

- [#10782](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10782)
- [#7120](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7120)
- [#7327](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/7327)

These issues are all closed and resolved and should be delivered with Update 2 from Visual Studio. If you update your Visual Studio to the newest Update everything should work fine, like in Visual Studio 2012 with the mentioned combination of `CTRL + ]`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew this was fixed in update 2. Updated VS 2015 to Update 3 and it is working now!